# Python - PIL Image open, How to open all image in the directory and keep it update

Tags: python, image, loops, directory, python-imaging-library

i follow tutorial on youtube
[This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg4c92pNFeo).

the problem is how to open all the images in the directory without declaring 1 by 1...

and name it like in the img_list array

here is part of the code :

```
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.jpg"))
my_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("2.jpg"))
my_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("3.jpg"))

img_list = [my_img, my_img1, my_img2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Tk, but you should be able to `glob()` the files like this:

```
import glob 

# Get list of JPEGs to process 
names = glob.glob('*.jpg')

# Open as images
images = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(name)) for name in names]
```

Comment: I see. And then how to keep the list update if there is any changes in the directory...

Comment: That depends a lot on what your application is and how it works and what technology and operating system it uses. At it simplest, you could run the `glob()` again every few seconds and see if the list differs from the old one. Other likely solutions might be to use `inotifywait()` something like this https://pypi.org/project/inotify/